# how to do on uncheck checkbox doesnot delete all

Tags: php

hello my function doesnot delete all one checkbox remains checked as i uncheked it but there is no effect on that i need help

here is my code

```
if(array_key_exists('assigned_ids',$this->input->post())){

    $select_assigned_ids = $this->input->post('assigned_ids[]');

/* delete previous entries for user_id */
 $q = 'Delete from section_permissions where user_id != 1 and section_id = 0 ';
 $this->section_permission_model->qwr($q); 

     if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
         foreach($select_assigned_ids as $tlusers){
             $data = array(
                        'user_id' => $tlusers,
                    );
            $test = $this->section_permission_model->insert($data);
            //echo"<pre>";print_r($test);die;
            } 
             $this->session->set_flashdata('success','Permissions updated successfully');
             redirect('admin/Evaluation/create_evaluation');
            }
 }else{
        /* delete previous entries for user_id */
 $q = 'Delete from section_permissions where user_id != 1 and section_id = 0 ';
 $this->section_permission_model->qwr($q);
 }
```

it works fine as i want but it doesn't not insert any record and delete  too but with flashdata it worked as i wanted

Comment: question not clear...It would be great if you will show your view code..

Comment: <?php echo form_open("");?>
<?php foreach($users as $user){ ?>
<ul class="name">
<li><span class="users_check">
 
 <input type="checkbox" name="assigned_ids[]"  <?=(in_array($user['user_id'],$team_leader))?'checked':''?> class="other" value="<?=$user['user_id']?>" ></span><p><?= $user['f_name']?> </p></li>
</ul>
 <? } ?> 
 
 <button id ="submit" class="btn btn-default">CREATE</button>
 <?php echo form_close();?>

Comment: as i uncheck all it doesnot delete anyone but if i uncheck one by one then delete but one remains uncheked

Comment: Code is not looking formated...Kindly edit your question and paste view code there.

Comment: have a look i have edited my question

Comment: see my answer below and do let me know your feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be the problem is on your sql query

```
if ($this->input->post()) {
    $select_assigned_ids = $this->input->post('assigned_ids[]');

    /* delete previous entries for user_id */
    $q = 'Delete from section_permissions where section_id = 0 ';
    $this->section_permission_model->qwr($q);
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        foreach($select_assigned_ids as $tlusers){
             $data = array(
                        'user_id' => $tlusers,
                    );
            $this->section_permission_model->insert($data);
        }
    }
}
```

Your delete query syntax may be wrong.

Comment: sorry but its doesnot work i used delete from  in my sql query forget to mention here and its not working

Comment: if ($this->input->post()) {
    
   $select_assigned_ids = $this->input->post('assigned_ids[]');
   
   /* delete previous entries for user_id */
      $q = 'Delete from section_permissions where user_id != 1 and section_id = 0 ';
   $this->section_permission_model->qwr($q); 

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
     foreach($select_assigned_ids as $tlusers){
      $data = array(
        'user_id' => $tlusers,
       );
                    $test = $this->section_permission_model->insert($data);
     //echo"<pre>";print_r($test);die;
  } 
  }
   }

Comment: please help  @ jithin its not delete as i unckeck all if i uncheck one by one then it deletes but still one remains checked

Answer (score 2):

I guess, You know that if you will `uncheck all` the checkbox and submit the form then you will not get values of checkbox in controller or model. Please see example below :-

**Correct way to do that** 
You need to check that either checkbox is checked or not...do that in your controller.

```
if(array_key_exists('assigned_ids',$this->input->post())){
    //First of all delete previous entries for user_id
    //Insert new records for user_id  (value = new checkbox values)

}else{
    //Checkbox is unchecked....
    //delete all previous entries for user_id
}
```

I hope it will help you.

Comment: it doesnot insert please help

Comment: if checkbox are uncheck then what condition i have to write please tell me that

Comment: If checkbox is checked then delete all previous entries for particular user and insert new values....
if checkbox is not checked then delete all entries for particular user

Comment: For complete code...I need db table structure and condition to delete or insert data...

Comment: please see controller code in my question m using that but not able to insert

Comment: I can't understand by your controller code...it would be great if you will share you table structure and explain what is the use of each attribute...

Comment: You wana save checkbox values for a particular user or all user...I'm little bit confused...do you wana store all checkbox values in one row or that will store in multiple row...

Comment: ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 permission_id | user_id | from_id | assigned_for | section_id
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

this is my db structure as i uncheck all it doesnot delete any record

Comment: Still you are doing the same think....It's too easy. I don't know what is not clear to you. Send me all detail over my email i will provide you full working module.

Comment: please have a look on my edited controller code in my question and please provide me solution what to do in that function so that it works

Comment: What is section_id?
Question :- Suppose you have 2 users in db and 4 check boxes in view files. If you select all checkbox then how many records will insert into db. I guess 8 records. Am i right?

Comment: section which is display to user_id

Comment: please again have a look on my question

Comment: my query i have executed it  on SQL  in phpmyadmin it work fine but don't know why  on view page it delete all records except one and that is the only one checked box is displayed as checked i tried everything but no luck

Comment: Can you share what query you are executing directly in phpmyadmin?

Comment: Also try below code
`foreach($select_assigned_ids as $tlusers){
             $data[] = array(
                        'user_id' => $tlusers,
                    );            
        }
$this->section_permission_model->insert_batch($data);`

Comment: Delete from section_permissions where section_id = 0

this one

Comment: Call to undefined method Section_permission_model::insert_batch() it was giving error

Comment: on delete query please tell me what to add so that it can delete user_id which is seleted from table doesnot matter how many tyime it exists and no section_id should be passed on querry